# How to get the current path in react router 6?

Tags: reactjs

In react-router-dom v5. I can get the current url and path by using `useRouteMatch`

```
const {path, url} = useRouteMatch() 

 path =  /moose/kite/:id
 url = /moose/kite/thisIsId
```

in react-router-dom v6. I can get the current url by using the pathName from `useLocation`

```
const location = useLocation()
location.pathname === /moose/kite/thisIsId
```

How to get path string as in v5. This string `/moose/kite/:id`

Answer (score 0):

Using `useMatch` hook

Learn more: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#replace-useroutematch-with-usematch

Comment: How to get `/moose/kite/:id` from `useMatch` ?

Answer (score 0):

It appears this is not as easy to do in React Router 6, compared to 5. I use a hook like this, but it's invconvenient in that you can only use this technique if you have an array of routes.

```js
export const useCurrentPath = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const [{ route }] = matchRoutes(routes, location) ?? [];

  return route.path;
};
```